# UICollectionViewCell pass indexpath.item to list

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

So I got this code where I want to be able to tap a created cell, then set a title to it. If I tap it once more, I want the cell to be selected (more cells will be tapped here), before i submit their data to an alert where i choose from a list of persisted models in the application. Is there an easy way to do this?

As seen in this picture:

[image]

The submit-button is disabled by default, but when items are selected it is enabled to show this alert as described earlier.

---

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let image = images[indexPath.item]

            if (image.label == "Tap to Edit") {
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Set image title", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alertController.addTextField()

                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { [weak self, weak alertController] _ in
                    guard let newTitle = alertController?.textFields?[0].text else {
                        return
                    }
                    image.label = newTitle
                    self?.collectionView.reloadData()
                })

                    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
                    present(alertController, animated: true)
            } else {
                // addToList

            }
        }
```

Comment: what is happening with your code currently ?

Comment: its just setting the title right ? now you want that if user reselect the same cell ... it shows tick mark that its selected ... and user can select multiple cells

Comment: @jawadAli That is correct. I would want the user to be able to select multiple cells, and then press "submit" to move on to the new alertController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a check .. if `image.label != "tap to edit"` then show selected image on that cell and put that indexpath in an array .... same is the case with other cells .. when user tap submit ... get all indexes from that array and perform action ?

Comment: This seems about what I would want to do. How would I do checks on wether or not the cell is tapped to get it high- or dehighlighted?

Comment: if your indexpath array has that indexpath .. then you need to deSelect that cell ... otherwise if image.label is set add that index path to array and show selected image over that cell ....

Comment: I see, how would i code this? I'm quite new to Swift. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: you need to declare an array ... in which you store index paths.... first try to do that .... if user tab first time .... check if that index exists in the array ... if yes ... remove it from the array ... if no .. check if the image.label is set .. if yes .. add that indexpath in array ... if no .. set its label (what you are doing right now) in your didselectrow method

Comment: Ok I see. If you are able to send me a codesnippet of how this would be done, I would really appreciate it. Feel free to create another answer to do so.

Comment: you can send me project .. i will do that

Comment: Here you go: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1id1SikbhQWs1uwiY0roqo7yvxBz9pJWW/view?usp=sharing